# Solving this PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this second order PDE: $-u_{xx}+2u_{xy}+3u_{yy}-\dfrac{1}{3}u_x+u_y=0$.
I've got up to $48V_st+4V_t=0$ and this implies $48V_s+4V=f(s)$. I'm stuck on how to finish solving this PDE.